# How to make Copy Local always True

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010. When I clean the solution the dll is disappearing from the bin\debug folder and 'COPY Local' is automatically set to False. When I rebuild the solution, the dll is showing up in that folder and 'Copy Local' attribute is still set to False.

How to make the dll should present in the bin\debug folder always. And the 'Copy Local' attribute  set to True.

Comment: I've marked all References at once, set Local Copy to true. VS doesn't set anything back to false. So what exactly are you doing? I'd like to reproduce that/your behaviour.

Comment: Not sure what product you are talking about, it doesn't sound anything like Visual Studio.  If you put any DLLs in the GAC then be sure to remove them again.

Comment: That's so 5 years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here, I found:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Toggling Copy Local to false and the to true adds "Private" metadata
There is a trick: set the reference Copy Local to false and then again to true, and Visual Studio adds the Private metadata automatically for that reference. At least VS 2010 does. I recently did this to solve an issue with our TFS Build server which for some weird reason had many Enterprise Library components installed in the GAC, so we had major issues when deploying our project from TFS Drop folder. That false/true trick saved us. Enter comment here.

---

[And Here, I found:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984582%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The project-assigned value of CopyLocal is determined in the following order:

1. If the reference is another project, called a project-to-project
   reference, then the value is true.
2. If the assembly is found in the global assembly cache, the value is false.
3. As a special case, the value for the mscorlib.dll reference is false.
4. If the assembly is found in the Framework SDK folder, then the value is false.
5. Otherwise, the value is true.

Comment: down vote explanation is helpful. Why is this wrong? This explicitly addresses VS-2010 - the tag on this question; it specifically describes how that guy got the attribute to be "true." The order of determining it's value shows that the dll should not be in the GAC, which supports @HansPassant comment.